# php to js variable not setting at run time

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, alert

issue : i am able to set and get run time variable value  ?
steps: onlick button random number,
expected output :alert pop in broswer and number should be shows inside alert .

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pass variable from PHP to JavaScript - Cyberster's Blog'</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<input type="button" value="random number " onclick="location='php2js2.php'" />

<script>

//     var js_var = "<?php echo $php_var; echo $randomString ?>";

//alert(js_var);

        var js_var_key = "<?php echo $RandomString(6); ?>";
        alert(js_var_key);

</script>
  </body>
</html>


<?php
function RandomString($length) {
    $keys = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a', 'z'));

    for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
    }
    return $key;
}

#$php_var = "Hello world from PHP";
#$length = 10;
#$randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);

?>
```

==

Comment: Your question is not clear .You mean you are not getting  alert(js_var_key); value?

Comment: Remove $ from RandomString in front of function name while calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not keep $ infront of RandomString..Please remove that and check and add this .. you will find the alert with a random number

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document ).ready(function() {
        var js_var_key = "<?php echo RandomString(6); ?>";
        alert(js_var_key);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var js_var_key = "<?php echo $RandomString(6); ?>";
```

change this line to  (remove $)

```
var js_var_key = "<?php echo RandomString(6); ?>";
```

and add
`$key=""` before
`for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {`

Comment: how to do ???? now i want use this code to show random string wothout relaoding page ?????Note page should not reload.

Comment: You cannot do it the way you have written the code.